# Counting triplets where each elements are from different groups

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say we have given groups with more elements each, is there easy way to count number of ways to choose three elements from different groups.

For example if our groups are $\{1\}, \{2\} \text { and } \{3, 4\}$. There are two  ways to form the triplets $\{1, 2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 4\}$.

I tried fixing all three groups but that works in $O(N^3)$, where $N$ is the number of groups. Is it possible to make it in $O(N)$?

Comment: Do you mean there can be $N>3$ groups?  (Because if there are exactly $N=3$ groups the answer is trivial.  But then I'm surprised your example has $N=3$.)

Comment: Yes, there can be N>3 groups

Comment: Can I assume all the groups are disjoint, i.e. no element appears in two or more groups?  If so, I have an $O(N)$ solution... Is this homework?  If so I will give you a hint, otherwise I will post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT.

This assumes the groups are disjoint, i.e. no element appears in multiple groups.

It turns out to be easier to count the complement.  You pick $3$ elements from the entire universe.

- How many $3$-subsets have all elements from the same group?  This can be counted easily in $O(N)$.
- How many $3$-subsets have all elements from only two different groups?  This can be counted easily in $O(N^2)$ and with a small trick can also be counted in $O(N)$.